# AIC & BIC of PyMC mixture model

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, mcmc, model-comparison

I am using PyMC to fit some data to a straight line. The data have outliers, so I adapted [some code](http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter8/fig_outlier_rejection.html) (third example at the link) written by Jake Vanderplas for his textbook. The method uses a vector variable `qi` to encode whether each individual data point belongs to the foreground model (which we are fitting to the line) or the background model, which we don't care about.

```
class lin_fit_ol(object):

    '''
    fit a straight line to one independent variable
        (`xi`, with zero errors) and one dependent variable
        (`yi`, with possibly heteroscedastic errors `dyi`)
    Outliers in `yi` are permitted

    Intended to be a complement to a straight-line fit, for model
        testing purposes

    Modified from Vanderplas's code
        (found at http://www.astroml.\
        org/book_figures/chapter8/fig_outlier_rejection.html)
    '''

    def __init__(self, xi, yi, dyi, value):

        self.xi, self.yi, self.dyi, self.value = xi, yi, dyi, value

        @pymc.stochastic
        def beta(value=np.array([0.5, 1.0])):
            """Slope and intercept parameters for a straight line.
            The likelihood corresponds to the prior probability of the parameters."""
            slope, intercept = value
            prob_intercept = 1 + 0 * intercept
            # uniform prior on theta = arctan(slope)
            # d[arctan(x)]/dx = 1 / (1 + x^2)
            prob_slope = np.log(1. / (1. + slope ** 2))
            return prob_intercept + prob_slope

        @pymc.deterministic
        def model(xi=xi, beta=beta):
            slope, intercept = beta
            return slope * xi + intercept

        # uniform prior on Pb, the fraction of bad points
        Pb = pymc.Uniform('Pb', 0, 1.0, value=0.1)

        # uniform prior on Yb, the centroid of the outlier distribution
        Yb = pymc.Uniform('Yb', -10000, 10000, value=0)

        # uniform prior on log(sigmab), the spread of the outlier distribution
        log_sigmab = pymc.Uniform('log_sigmab', -10, 10, value=5)

        # qi is bernoulli distributed
        # Note: this syntax requires pymc version 2.2
        qi = pymc.Bernoulli('qi', p=1 - Pb, value=np.ones(len(xi)))

        @pymc.deterministic
        def sigmab(log_sigmab=log_sigmab):
            return np.exp(log_sigmab)

        def outlier_likelihood(yi, mu, dyi, qi, Yb, sigmab):
            """likelihood for full outlier posterior"""
            Vi = dyi ** 2
            Vb = sigmab ** 2

            root2pi = np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)

            logL_in = -0.5 * np.sum(
                qi * (np.log(2 * np.pi * Vi) + (yi - mu) ** 2 / Vi))

            logL_out = -0.5 * np.sum(
                (1 - qi) * (np.log(2 * np.pi * (Vi + Vb)) +
                            (yi - Yb) ** 2 / (Vi + Vb)))

            return logL_out + logL_in

        OutlierNormal = pymc.stochastic_from_dist(
            'outliernormal', logp=outlier_likelihood, dtype=np.float,
            mv=True)

        y_outlier = OutlierNormal(
            'y_outlier', mu=model, dyi=dyi, Yb=Yb, sigmab=sigmab, qi=qi,
            observed=True, value=yi)

        self.M = dict(y_outlier=y_outlier, beta=beta, model=model,
                      qi=qi, Pb=Pb, Yb=Yb, log_sigmab=log_sigmab,
                      sigmab=sigmab)

        self.sample_invoked = False

    def sample(self, iter, burn, calc_deviance=True):
        self.S0 = pymc.MCMC(self.M)
        self.S0.sample(iter=iter, burn=burn)
        self.trace = self.S0.trace('beta')
        self.btrace = self.trace[:, 0]
        self.mtrace = self.trace[:, 1]

        self.sample_invoked = True

    def triangle(self):
        assert self.sample_invoked == True, \
            'Must sample first! Use sample(iter, burn)'

        corner(self.trace[:], labels=['$m$', '$b$'])

    def plot(self, xlab='$x$', ylab='$y$'):
        # plot the data points
        plt.errorbar(self.xi, self.yi, yerr=self.dyi, fmt='.k')

        # do some shimmying to get quantile bounds
        xa = np.linspace(self.xi.min(), self.xi.max(), 100)
        A = np.vander(xa, 2)
        # generate all possible lines
        lines = np.dot(self.trace[:], A.T)
        quantiles = np.percentile(lines, [16, 84], axis=0)
        plt.fill_between(xa, quantiles[0], quantiles[1],
                         color="#8d44ad", alpha=0.5)

        # plot circles around points identified as outliers
        qi = self.S0.trace('qi')[:]
        Pi = qi.astype(float).mean(0)
        outlier_x = self.xi[Pi < 0.32]
        outlier_y = self.yi[Pi < 0.32]
        plt.scatter(outlier_x, outlier_y, lw=1, s=400, alpha=0.5,
                    facecolors='none', edgecolors='red')

        plt.xlabel(xlab)
        plt.ylabel(ylab)

    def ICs(self):
        self.MAP = pymc.MAP(self.M)
        self.MAP.fit()

        self.BIC = self.MAP.BIC
        self.AIC = self.MAP.AIC
        self.logp = self.MAP.logp
        self.logp_at_max = self.MAP.logp_at_max
        return self.AIC, self.BIC
```

So, when we calculate the BIC and AIC using this model, we get very large values (since there are lots of points). This makes total sense. However, this disfavors having many data points, which irks me. Plus, the large AIC and BIC would make a casual observer believe that the other model (which fits poorly as a result of the outliers) is *actually the better model*.

Am I missing a subtlety of the BIC and AIC here, or is a harsh reality of using mixture models that you always have to use a bunch of extra binary parameters to denote the membership of your datapoints?

Comment: I don't usually use AIC or BIC when comparing models of different data sets. Both criteria depend on the sample size so they, as you observe, increase with the sample size. I tend only to use them when comparing different models for the same data set. I agree it seems strange to use AIC or BIC as a sort of cost function when deciding whether to include or exclude a data point in your model.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book ["Introduction to statistical learning"](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf)

On page 212 you find the formulas for AIC and BIC. In each of these formulas the sample number is in the denominator. Hence, the result should not be influenced by the number of samples. At least not in that obvious way.